# Http Post request around 100 Mb

Tags: c#, web-services, http, post

I would like to know if a Http Post request with a body size around 100Mb is too much ?
I though to have a rest with a MD5 to confirm th integrity of the contains.

Is it a good way ?

PS:  Sorry for my poor english ;-)

Comment: Depends on what the server is configured to accept.

Comment: A good way for doing what? You haven't said what you're trying to achieve. File transfer?

Comment: - the server is IIS 6

- I had to transfert around 100Mb of information.

I don't want to use a ftp file system, it should be to hard to manage it. I am searching an alternative way.
Then, the post will be able to work ?

Comment: I can't remember but I'm sure IIS has a default limit of 4MB or some such. You can change the configuration but you'd have to go and read the documentation.

Comment: - IIS limit is 4GB, there is no problem for him.
I am affraid to lost some information, and a lot of other problem that i don't know yet